# Dynamic VF Binding error

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I'm facing the exact same issue described here [Error: Incorrect parameter type for subscript. Expected Text, received SetValue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251709/error-incorrect-parameter-type-for-subscript-expected-text-received-setvalue)

I'm trying to populate a table with a list of input fields, where the actual fields are determined at run time, using dynamic vf binding.

I have the following code in my controller extension

```
public Lead lead {get;set;}
public Set<String> fieldsToPopulate {get; set;}
```

Then in my page, I'm looping through the set, which contains the API name of some fields in the Lead object

```
 <apex:repeat value="{!fieldsToPopulate}" var="f">
     <apex:inputField value="{!Lead[f]}"/>
  </apex:repeat>
```

The above results in the following error when saving the page

**Incorrect parameter type for subscript. Expected Text, received SetValue**

If I simply print the field name, instead of using an inputField, the field name is displayed correctly.

This follow the pattern described in the official visualforce guide, right here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_sample_standard.htm?search_text=dynamic

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, the list of field api names must be a **list**, it cannot be a **set**, so I changed

```
public Set<String> fieldsToPopulate {get; set;}
```

to

```
public List<String> fieldsToPopulate {get; set;}
```

And it resolved the issue.